# Instruction order in a transaction

Tags: instructions, priority-fees

I'm currently exploring priority fee in Solana transaction, so I'm wondering should I add the `setComputeUnitPrice` as the first instruction or the order doesn't matter? Extending the concept, the order of instruction in a transaction matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of instructions **does** matter.

If you call an account that is expected to be initialized then initialize it in the next instruction. Your transaction **will** fail.

For the fees, the default computation unit limit is set to 200k. If you exceed that limit in the instructions before extending the computation limit. Your transaction **will** fail.

**Example**
A transaction that has 3 instructions in this order:

- Instruction 1 Uses 150k
- Instruction 2 Uses 70k
- Instruction 3 Extend the compute limit

Your transaction **will** fail in the second instruction since 150k + 70k > 200k.

If we swap instruction 2 and instruction 3. The transaction **will** be valid.

A good practice is calling `setComputeUnitLimit` and `setComputeUnitPrice` first in your transaction.

Answer (score 2):

From the example on Solana Cookbook, it seems like requests for compute budget/priority fee should be added first to a new transaction

https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-change-compute-budget-fee-priority-for-a-transaction

```
const modifyComputeUnits = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ 
  units: 1000000 
});

const addPriorityFee = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({ 
  microLamports: 1 
});

const transaction = new Transaction()
.add(modifyComputeUnits)
.add(addPriorityFee)
.add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      toPubkey: toAccount,
      lamports: 10000000,
    })
  );
```

The sequence of instructions in a transaction is the order in which they will be executed